# How to handle status messages in an MVC-based website?

Tags: php, error-handling, messaging

It's clear that you should be using exceptions to handle errors in your app. But should you really use the incorporated messages to show them to the actual user?

If so, you'd have to internationalize those messages which is still manageable. But what about simple status information like "file successfully stored"? Those are not errors, obviously, so you can't use exceptions for them. How would you handle those?

I don't like the thought of having to deal with them for each area individually, but would prefer a global, unified way to handle error *and* simple status messages that will be shown to the user. What's the best way to do that? On the template level maybe? Is that the right place?

How about an event system, where the lowest severity/level/type would be a notice and the highest a fatal error? Is that feasible?

Comment: Why would you expose exceptions to users? Those errors are for developers! Catch the exception and display a meaningful message to the user and log the error to a file/db/email/where ever.

Comment: That's what I'm asking in my 2nd sentence :) Why not use a message that's useful for both? And if not, how and where would you pull them apart?

Comment: I am yet to find an instance where the result of an exception is directly applicable to the user. Perhaps a form validation exception, but even still I would catch them and add a translation for the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a `FlashMessage` class for this purpose. It stores the message in a session and displays on the next page load. This way you can have a space in all your templates for displaying messages and if there is one set it will be displayed. You can then redirect and POST onto any page and the message will be displayed.

Comment: I ended up using something like you described: a Registry that holds all responses from anywhere in the code. The interesting part is the error method. You pass an exception into that which holds the internal error message, and an error message to show to the user. Then the exception is actually being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I personally do that on the template level.

For example...

Controller:

```
if(UsersModel::addNewUser($username)){
  $this->set("user_added", true);
}
```

In the template:

```
<?
    if(!empty($user_added)){
    ?>
        <p>User added successfully!</p>
    <?
    }
?>
```

No problems with i18n (using gettext) here too and Controller stays clear:

```
if(!empty($user_added)){
        ?>
            <p><?=_("User added successfully!");?></p>
        <?
}
```

Comment: That's kind of what I want to avoid - testing for a _specific_ condition in each _individual_ template. I'd like something more general like: if there's a message (or messages), add it (them) to the output somehow.